# How to filter array based on nested array data?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with a few objects:

```js
const x = [
  {label: 'a', data: [0,0]},
  {label: 'b', data: [0,0]},
  {label: 'c', data: [0,1]}
  {label: 'd', data: [0,1]},
]
```

I want to filter out the objects where the data values are equal to 0 and end up with:

```js
const x = [
  {label: 'c', data: [0,1]}
  {label: 'd', data: [0,1]},
]
```

I tried:

```js
const result = x.filter((x) => {
    return x.data.filter((value) => value > 0);
});
```

expecting the `.filter()` to only return objects where the value would be higher than 0, but this is not working as expected.

Comment: From the documentation: "[It should return a truthy to keep the element in the resulting array, and a falsy value otherwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=nl#parameters)". You are returning the result of `.filter()`, which is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method always returns an array, which is considered a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. So the outer `.filter()` keeps all objects. Instead, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return `true` if any of the values in the `data` array are `> 0` to keep the object in the resulting array:

```js
const x = [ {label: 'a', data: [0,0]}, {label: 'b', data: [0,0]}, {label: 'c', data: [0,1]}, {label: 'd', data: [0,1]}, ];

const result = x.filter((x) => {
  return x.data.some((value) => value > 0);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on if some values in data object inside the main array are not 0 and then keep them in the array.

```js
const x = [
  { label: 'a', data: [0, 0] },
  { label: 'b', data: [0, 0] },
  { label: 'c', data: [0, 1] },
  { label: 'd', data: [0, 1] },
]
const res = x.filter(el => el.data.some(y => y!=0))
console.log(res)
```